# Why @ConfigurationProperties does not automatically register as a bean if set @EnableConfigurationProperties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an example here：

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hello")
public class MyProperties {
    
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)
public class MyConfig {
}
```

application.properties

```xml
hello.name=zhangsan
```

My Unit test：

```java
@SpringBootTest
class SpringLearnApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MyProperties myProperties;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(myProperties.getName()); 
    }
}
```

And then there's an anomaly:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.github.spring_learn.conf.MyProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

I consulted the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` note：

Enable support for @ConfigurationProperties annotated beans. @ConfigurationProperties beans can be registered in the standard way (for example using @Bean methods) or, for convenience, can be specified directly on this annotation.

**Doesn't it mean to quickly register `@ConfigurationProperties` as `Spring Bean` ?**

**Of course, I can register use `@compent`,`@bean`,`@configuation`... like this**

```
@Component // or @Configuation
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hello")
public class MyProperties {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**and I don't even need it `MyConfig`,I think it's much simpler**

**So, since `@EnableConfigurationProperties` cannot be registered as a bean, what does it do?**

Comment: I find it more convenient to use the bean annotations directly instead of creating a new class

Answer (score 2):

**@EnableConfigurationProperties** allows you to support annotated @ConfigurationProperties classes in our application. However, it's worth noting that the Spring Boot documentation says that every project automatically includes **@EnableConfigurationProperties**. Therefore, **@ConfigurationProperties** support is implicitly enabled in every Spring Boot application.

If spring boot did not automatically enable ConfigurationProperties support, and you would not specify this through the **@EnableConfigurationProperties** annotation, then the **@ConfigurationProperties** annotation would simply be ignored.

The **@Configuratio**n annotation allows spring to define your class as a bean provider.

Even if your class is marked with the **@EnableConfigurationProperties** annotation, it cannot become a bean source, you must also add the **@Configuration** annotation.

You can combine **@Component** and **@ConfigurationProperties**, **@Bean** and **@ConfigurationProperties**, or **@Component** and **@Value**.

Comment: so,If this is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Place `@Configuration` on the `MyConfig` object:

```java
// here you've defined everything right
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hello")
public class MyProperties {
    
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Configuration // <----- this was missing
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class) 
public class MyConfig  {
   

   // ... here beans will be defined...
   @Bean
   public MySampleBean mySampleBean(MyProperties config) {
     return new MySampleBean(config.getName());
   }
}
```

Here I've shown an example of `MySampleBean` that might be aware of some configuration property (`config.name`) in this case

**Update 1**
Answering OP's comment:

> Why don't I just use bean annotations like @compent,@configuation in MyProperties .Class,and use @Autowired in MyConfig

Basically because `@Configuration` is the place to define beans, its not a bean by itself in a sense that it should be used like a unit that has some business logic of your application. It has happened to be driven by spring for internal reasons, but I suggest to not treat the `@Configuration` classes like regular beans. The same holds for `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated classes: Its a way to load configuration properties / use them in the application. This is more like a "special language" to configure spring related stuff (DSL if you wish). So You can create @Component annotated beans of your business alternatively to the `@Configuration` annotated classes, spring supports both ways of the bean definitions, in in any case you can inject Configuration Properties, however if you want to "plug in" the configuration properties with `@EnableConfigurationProperties` you should use it on a `@Configuration` annotated class.

Comment: Why don't I just use bean annotations like `@compent`,`@configuation` in MyProperties .Class,and use `@Autowired` in MyConfig

Comment: @Aries Zero: Please see the update on the answer